# Python: bz2 and lzma in mode 'wt' don't write the BOM (while gzip does). Why?

Tags: python, compression, utf, byte-order-mark

The following code writes a compressed text file using gzip, bz2 and lzma, then reads and prints its binary content.

```
import bz2
import gzip
import lzma
import os


def test(encoding):
    print(encoding)
    for module in [gzip, bz2, lzma]:

        path = '/tmp/test.txt.%s' % module.__name__
        if os.path.exists(path):
            os.remove(path)

        with module.open(path, 'wt', encoding=encoding) as fout:
            fout.write('Ciao')

        with module.open(path, 'rb') as fin:
            print("%8s" % module.__name__, 'bytes:', fin.read())


test('utf-16')
print('')
test('utf-32')
```

The output is:

```
utf-16
    gzip bytes: b'\xff\xfeC\x00i\x00a\x00o\x00'
     bz2 bytes: b'C\x00i\x00a\x00o\x00'
    lzma bytes: b'C\x00i\x00a\x00o\x00'

utf-32
    gzip bytes: b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00'
     bz2 bytes: b'C\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00'
    lzma bytes: b'C\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00'
```

As you can see, bz2 and lzma don't write the BOM (Byte Order Mark), while gzip does as expected. This means that if I attempt to read the bz2/lzma files in text mode (e.g. `bz2.open(path, 'rt', encoding='utf-16')`), a `UnicodeError` is raised complaining for the missing BOM.

Why is that? Is it a bug?

Comment: looks like a bug or a limitation. You should use bnary mode.

Comment: Sure, I was just curious about it. It could be useful for a future reader to know that it's possible to use an incremental encoder for adding the BOM to an encoded string only the first time it is used (str.encode on the other hand adds the BOM every single time):

    `encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()`

Comment: the documentation for gzip & bz2 modules are copy/paste from each other in that section, but it behaves differently with BOM... weird.

Comment: Yes, and the code works the same. A binary writer is wrapped by a `io.TextIOWrapper`. Apparently, it's this wrapper that, for some reason, skips the BOM.

Comment: TextIOWrapper is used for both if you check the documentation. Maybe you could try with objects / binary mode and use TextIOWrapper manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. In short: yes, it's definitely a bug of the C implementation of `io.TextIOWrapper`.

When you open a file in text mode (compressed or not) what is returned is a `io.TextIOWrapper` that wraps a binary file reader. `io.TextIOWrapper` is implemented in C in the `_io` extension module. It turns out that there is also a Python implementation of the `io` module, namely the `_pyio` module. `_pyio.TextIOWrapper` works as expected, so it's definitely a bug of the C implementation.

The following code demonstrates the issue:

```
import bz2
import io
import _pyio

def test(io_module, encoding='utf-16'):
    path = '/tmp/test.txt.bz2'

    with io_module.TextIOWrapper(bz2.open(path, 'w'), encoding=encoding) as fout:
        fout.write('Ciao')

    with bz2.open(path, 'rb') as fin:
        print("%5s" % io_module.__name__, 'bytes:', fin.read())


test(io)
test(_pyio)
```

which prints:

```
   io bytes: b'C\x00i\x00a\x00o\x00'
_pyio bytes: b'\xff\xfeC\x00i\x00a\x00o\x00'
```